# JS - Magnetic cursor not working when not loaded in viewport

Tags: javascript

I have a div in my navigation on top of the page that has a magnetic effect when the cursor comes closer it will snap to it.

But when you are halfway the page and hit refresh, then the page will load at that point and the magnetic box is not in the viewport. Then you scroll to the magnetic div and the effect will not work...

It only works when you are on top of the page when the page loads... I've made a pen but it's difficult to recreate the problem in there. Maybe someone is familiair with this?

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="mag magnet-btn">magnetic box</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Link to my pen: https://codepen.io/mdia/pen/bGpGJNj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to base the y-axis on the element's position - not on the `window` object's `scrollY`. That is why it won't initialize correctly on a different window scroll position other than the topmost.

```
var viewportOffset = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
```

Comment: You're my hero! Thanks